# How to implement a SearchByID?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Good afternoon all!

As a part of getting a better grip on some of the most aspects of object based programming, I've started to attempt something far larger than I have done in the past. Hereby I'm trying to learn about inheritance, code reuse, using classes far more extensively, and so on.
For this purpose I am trying to piece together all the parts required for a basic RPG/dungeon crawler.
I know this has been done a billion times before, but I find that actually trying to code something like it takes you through a lot more problems than you might think, which is a great way to learn (I think).

For now I have only loaded up a WPF application, since my interest is 95% on being able to piece together the working classes, routines, functions, etc. And not so much interested in how it will look. I am actually reading up on XNA, but since I am mostly trying to get a grip on the basic workings, I don't want to complicate those aspects with the graphical side of things just yet.

The problem I am now facing is that when I would a character to attack or defend, it should know from which other character it came, or to which one it should be pointed. I figured I could either use a GUID, or a manually appointed ID. But the problem is that I don't really know how I can implement such a thing.
The thing that I figured was that I could maybe add a reference to an array (Character[]), and have a SearchByID function loop through them to find the right one, and return it. Like so:

```
internal Character SearchByID(string _ID)
{
   foreach(Character charToFind in Character[])
   {
       if(charToFind.ID == _ID)
       return charToFind;
   }
}
```

This of course has to be altered a bit due to the return at the moment, but just to give you an idea.
What I am stuck on is how to create the appropriate array outside of the "Character"-class? I can fill it up just fine, but how do I go about having it added above class level?
The way the "Character"-class is built up is that every new character instantiates from the Character class. The constructor then loads the appropriate values. But other than this, I see no possibility to initialize an array outside of this.

If it is preferable to post the entire code that I have, that will be no problem at all!

Thanks for any insights you may provide me with.

Comment: it's object oriented programming not object based programming, fyi

Comment: There should be some sort of control class (usually Game) that runs the game loop and holds all characters. Collision detection handles who hit who.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want a way to insert characters in an array when they are instantiated..

You can make a **static** array or list

So,your class in my opinion should be

```
class Character
{
    static List<Character> characterList=new List<Character>();//all characters are here
    public Character(string id,...)
    {
     //initialize your object
     characterList.Add(this);//store them in the list as and when created
    }

    internal Character SearchByID(string _ID)
    {
       foreach(Character charToFind in characterList)
       {
       if(charToFind.ID == _ID)
       return charToFind;
       }
    }
}
```

As you may be knowing `static` members are associated with the `class` not with the `object`.So,when you create a new `character` object it would be automatically added to the `characterList`

Comment: Given the set up that I currently have, I think this will fit in really nicely, and provide me with the functionality I am seeking. I did try a static before posting, but by the looks of it applied it completely wrong.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-del if this has answer has helped you can accept it or atleast upvote

Comment: Sorry for not upvoting/accepting answer. Will do so in a minute.
Thing that hit me the most about the answers that I've gotten is that they are all good ways to implement the feature, and all of the replies have had a piece of the logic that was required or necessary.
With this came the inevitable (and somewhat humbling) conclusion that I might not have been as ready for my practise example as I thought. This has been a GREAT learning experience in that sense, and has led me to go back to the drawing board, and re-read some of the books, look up more samples, and do some more studies.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use the Character-class and pass other Characters to it, for example:

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int HitPoints { get; private set; }

    public int Offense { get; private set; }

    public int Defense { get; private set; }

    public Character(string name, int hitPoints, int offense, int defense)
    {
        Name = name;
        HitPoints = hitPoints;
        Offense = offense;
        Defense = defense;
    }

    public void Defend(Character source)
    {
        HitPoints = HitPoints - (source.Offense - Defense);
        if (HitPoints <= 0)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} died", Name);
        }
    }

    public void Attack(Character target)
    {
        // Here you can call the other character's defend with this char as an attacker
        target.Defend(this);
        if (target.HitPoints <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} killed {1}", Name, target.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing with object oriented programming is that you have to start thinking in objects. Objects are like boxes when they're concrete. You can make new ones and give them some properties, like a name, height, width, hitpoints, whatever. You can also let these objects perform actions. Now a simple box won't do much itself, but a character can do various things, so it makes sense to put these actions in the Character-class.

Besides having Characters, you might have a Game-class which manages the game-state, characters, monsters, treasure chests etc...

Now this simple example may cause you to gain HitPoints when your defense is higher than the attacker's offense, but that's details, I'll leave the exact implementation up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sorry, had to edit this due to not being all that familiar with the comment system here.
Thanks for such a detailed explanation. I actually had a fairly similar way of implementing your above code, though I found some good pointers for my own!
I will attempt the static first, but am very happy that you took the time to write the above!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are dealing with seperate processes, e.g. client-server, you probably don't want to use "Id"s at all.

Whereever you are passing `string _ID` around, pass the actual `Character` instead. This saves you looking up in an array or whatever.

Post more code, and I can show you what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The _ID string is just a way to look for a specific Character. After which the complete Character will be returned.

Comment: I understand, but at the point you reduce the character down to just an id - simply don't do that, keep it as a `Character` then you won't need to look it up. See Davio's answer - which is what I am talking about. Or post all your code and I'll show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary, instantiated in your controller class:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Character> _characterList = new Dictionary<Guid, Character>();
```

Initialise:

```
var someCharacter = new Character() { stats = something };
var otherCharacter = new Character() { stats = anotherThing };

var char1Id = Guid.NewGuid();
var char2Id = Guid.NewGuid();

_characterList.Add(char1Id, someCharacter);
_characterList.Add(char2Id, otherCharacter);
```

then, to access characters:

```
var charToFind = _characterList[char1Id];
```

or

```
var charToFind = _characterList.Single(c => c.Name = "Fred The Killer");
```

or whatever else...

Comment: This might also be a good way of doing things. For now I will attempt the response from Fake.It.Till.U.Make.It but if that proves unsuccessful, I will attempt the use of a Dictionary. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Check out keyed collection

[KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

It is like a dictionary where the key is a property of class.
You will be able to reference a Character with
Characters[id]
Syntax

On your Character class overrite GetHashCode and Equals for performance.
If you use Int32 for the ID then you will get a perfect hash.
Very fast and O(1).